# How do multiple thenReturn work in Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, testcase

I have a following line using Mockito:

```java
when(mock.method()).thenReturn(foo).thenReturn(bar).thenThrow(new Exception("test"));
```

Is the above statement same as:

```java
when(mock.method()).thenReturn(foo)thenThrow(new Exception("test"));
when(mock.method()).thenReturn(bar).thenThrow(new Exception("test"));
```

Please can anyone explain me, how would `thenReturn` be executed?
How does it work?

Comment: did you try to find out?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look in Mockito's [documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html) will provide the answer.

```
 //you can set different behavior for consecutive method calls.
//Last stubbing (e.g: thenReturn("foo")) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
.thenReturn("foo");

//Alternative, shorter version for consecutive stubbing:
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
.thenReturn("one", "two");
//is the same as:
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
.thenReturn("one")
.thenReturn("two");
```

Basically, calling the **thenReturn** multiple times will define how the method will behave in multiple calls.